# Paperclip not displaying image (rails api)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

I have a user module and I have generated paperclip attachment: profile_pic

user.rb:

```
has_attached_file :profile_pic,
style: { :medium => "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

controller:

```
image_base = params[:manager][:profile_pic]
if image_base != nil
   image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(image_base)
   image.original_filename = params[:manager][:file_name]
   current_user.profile_pic = image
   current_user.errors.delete(:profile_pic)
   current_user.save 
end
```

config/initializers/paperclip.rb:

```
Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register
```

It's not showing any errors but If I am trying to display the image, it gives me following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/managers/profile_pics/000/000/008/original/icon_new.png"):
```

When I am trying in console like:

```
user.profile_pic.display
/system/managers/profile_pics/000/000/008/original/icon_new.png? 
1556082410 => nil
```

Picture was saved in public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with production mode and Solved this by adding the following line in production.rb

```
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

The default folder is the following, so Paperclip uploaded to the right place:
`:rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename`

But it looks like you are having troubles accessing the right location.  Have you tried `user.profile_pic.url`?  I tried on my working example, both `.display` and `.url` are the same but I use an AWS S3 bucket.

`user.profile_pic.url` should be where to find the file on the web.

`user.profile_pic.path` should be where to find the file on the file system.

Comment: url : /system/managers/profile_pics/000/000/008/original/icon_new.png?1556083471

Comment: /system/managers/profile_pics/000/000/008/original/icon_new.png?1556083471 => nil